# C - Fast conversion between binary and hex representations

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation, representation

Reading or writing a C code, I often have difficulties translating the numbers from the binary to the hex representations and back. Usually, different masks like `0xAAAA5555` are used very often in low-level programming, but it's difficult to recognize a special pattern of bits they represent. Is there any easy-to-remember rule how to do it fast in the mind?

Comment: other than 0 and F, which are easy, you have to know the bits. ore use the windows calc :)

Comment: These low-level constants are going to be very context-dependent, so the only likely approach is developing your experience of that context.

Comment: Write out a conversion chart on a post-it note and stick it to your monitor bevel.  0=0000, 1=0001, 2=0010, 3=0011, 4=0100, ..., F=1111.  By the time the post-it adhesive gives, you likely have them memorized or move on to another project.   The 'digits' most commonly used for masking are the ones with either a single bit or a group of adjacent bits.  One-bit: 1, 2, 4, 8; Two bits: 3, 6, C; Three Bits: 7, E; Four: F.  The ones I still sometime have to think about are those with gaps between bits: 5, 9, A, B, D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each hex digit map exactly on 4 bit, I usually keep in mind the 8421 weights of each of these bits, so it is very easy to do even an in mind conversion ie

A = 10 = 8+2 = 1010 ... 
5 = 4+1 = 0101

just keep the **8-4-2-1** weights in mind.

```
A        5     
8+4+2+1  8+4+2+1
1 0 1 0  0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I always find easy to map HEX to BINARY numbers. Since each **hex digit** can be directly mapped to a **four digit binary number**, you can think of:

```
> 0xA4
```

As

```
> b 1010 0100
>   ---- ---- (4 binary digits for each part)
>     A    4
```

Comment: it's easy, but how about reverse mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is calculated by dividing the base 10 representation by 2 and stringing the remainders in reverse order. I do this in my head, seems to work.

So you say what does `0xAAAA5555` look like

I just work out what A looks like and 5 looks like by doing

```
A = 10

10 / 2 = 5 r 0 
 5 / 2 = 2 r 1
 2 / 2 = 1 r 0
 1 / 2 = 0 r 1
```

so I know the A's look like `1010` (Note that 4 fingers are a good way to remember the remainders!)

You can string blocks of 4 bits together, so A A is 1010 1010. To convert binary back to hex, I always go through base 10 again by summing up the powers of 2. You can do this by forming blocks of 4 bits (padding with 0s) and string the results.

so `111011101` is `0001 1101 1101`  which is `(1) (1 + 4 + 8) (1 + 4 + 8) = 1 13 13` which is `1DD`